# Is there an archive for older versions of Chrome Extensions?

Tags: google-chrome-extension, chrome-web-store

I was wondering if there is an established way for getting older versions of extensions available in Chrome Web Store. Does Google keep an archive similar to Mozilla, or are the old versions gone forever as soon as a newer version becomes available?

Thank you.

Answer (score 40):

There's a website doing it: [crx4chrome.com](http://www.crx4chrome.com/)

Comment: v helpful. question - I presume these extensions will autoupdate themselves back to the latest and some intervention needs to be done?

Comment: Yes, it should auto-update, if you don't want it to, you have to [load it as an unpacked extension](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24577024/install-chrome-extension-not-in-the-store/24577660#24577660)

Comment: You can go to their github page, select older version and load into developer version of chrome extensions. Using a third party to provide the crx which you load into browser can be unsafe.

Comment: Looking forward to get such page like "crx.dam.io" for Firefox.

Comment: I can't find some extensions in it... One of my extensions was compromised and i'd like to know since when I've been spied on... Googles tools are horrendously ineffective at this

Answer (score 5):

Gone forever. Link for the extension file stays always the same while versions change. Your best shot to get the old version of some extension is to fetch it from github/bitbucket/etc (if source is available there) or simply ask extension author to send you the code for older version. Then, you can run the code using 'load unpacked extension...' feature on extensions page (be sure to check the 'developer mode' checkbox first).

Comment: Unfortunately none of those are options sometimes. I just lost all of my extensions because of an ancient bug in Chrome that has still not been fixed, and because I am using Chromium 11 (I HATE newer versions), I cannot get Session Buddy back whatsoever because the Chrome devs refuse to support anything but the TOT (not that Google doesn’t have the frakking space to store everything forever like dishonestly claim).

Comment: @Synetech, which ancient bug do you refer to?