# Install Chrome extension form outside the Chrome Web Store

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I have developed a Chrome extension and I have packed it.
I sent my extension to some people to try it, but Chrome started to block extensions that it does not find in the store.

Is there any way to install my extension without getting blocked by Chrome?

**EDIT**
Is there any way to install extension as developer mode? I read that only extensions that installed  in developer mode will not blocked.

Answer (score 69, accepted):

For regular Windows users who are not skilled with computers, it is **practically not possible** to install and use extensions from outside the Chrome Web Store.

Users of other operating systems (Linux, Mac, Chrome OS) can easily install unpacked extensions (in developer mode).
Windows users can also load an unpacked extension, but they will always see an information bubble with "Disable developer mode extensions" when they start Chrome or open a new incognito window, which is really annoying. The only way for Windows users to use unpacked extensions without such dialogs is to switch to Chrome on the developer channel, by installing https://www.google.com/chrome/browser/index.html?extra=devchannel#eula.

Extensions can be [loaded in unpacked mode](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/getstarted#unpacked) by following the following steps:

1. Visit `chrome://extensions` (via omnibox or menu -> Tools -> Extensions).
2. Enable Developer mode by ticking the checkbox in the upper-right corner.
3. Click on the "Load unpacked extension..." button.
4. Select the directory containing your **unpacked** extension.

If you have a `crx` file, then it needs to be extracted first. CRX files are zip files with a different header. Any capable zip program should be able to open it. If you don't have such a program, I recommend [7-zip](http://www.7-zip.org/).

These steps will work for almost every extension, except extensions that rely on their extension ID. If you use the previous method, you will get an extension with a random extension ID. If it is important to preserve the extension ID, then you need to know the public key of your CRX file and insert this in your manifest.json. I have previously given a detailed explanation on how to get and use this key at https://stackoverflow.com/a/21500707.

Comment: Is dev mode on windows available in the prod line too now?

Comment: To disable the annoying warning on all release channels of Chrome use [dll patcher](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30287907/how-to-hack-chrome-dll-to-get-rid-of-the-disable-developer-mode-extensions-pop/30361260#30361260)

Comment: Why is Windows different?

Comment: @Melab Because those Windows users were mainly affected by unwanted sideloaded extensions.

Comment: For regular Windows users, it is **quite possible** to install extensions from outside the Chrome Web Store. Look at the answer below. Testers can be provided with a registry file that whitelists the extension sent to them.

Answer (score 27):

For Windows, you can also whitelist your extension through Windows policies. The full steps are details in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38011386/5099839), but there are quicker steps:

1. Create the registry key `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Policies\Google\Chrome\ExtensionInstallAllowlist`.
2. For each extension you want to whitelist, add a string value whose name should be a sequence number (starting at 1) and value is the extension ID.

For instance, in order to whitelist 2 extensions with ID `aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa` and `bbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb`, create a string value with name `1` and value `aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa`, and a second value with name `2` and value `bbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb`. This can be sum up by this registry file:

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Policies\Google\Chrome]

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Policies\Google\Chrome\ExtensionInstallAllowlist]
"1"="aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa"
"2"="bbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb"
```

EDIT: actually, [Chromium docs](https://chromeenterprise.google/policies/#ExtensionInstallAllowlist) also indicate how to do it for other OS.

EDIT (06/05/2022): [ExtensionInstallWhitelist](https://chromeenterprise.google/policies/#ExtensionInstallWhitelist) is deprecated since Chrome 100, it has been renamed to ExtensionInstallAllowlist (answer updated)

Comment: What if the extension I want to whilelist is unpacked, thus having a random ID?

Comment: @CaginUludamar then pack it by pressing "pack extension"