# How to get rid of "disable developer mode extensions" pop-up

Tags: windows, google-chrome

Recently Google added this annoying pop up to the dev channel.

Someone answered here ([Disable developer mode extensions pop up in Chrome](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23055651/disable-developer-mode-extensions-pop-up)) to edit the chrome.dll to get rid of the pop up.

However, the method described there does not seem to work anymore.

Additionally, it would be nice to have a batch script that patches chrome.dll should Google push a new update.

EDIT: Open to new hacks, since wOxxOm stopped maintaining his useful script (the manual method seems to be outdated as well)

Comment: Chrome now shows this irritating alert every time you open a new incognito session. It wasn't so bad when you only had to dismiss it once when you start the browser, but now it's really getting on my nerves. I think they made this change in version 64, released on 2018-01-24.

Comment: See also https://www.ghacks.net/2017/07/04/hide-chromes-disable-developer-mode-extensions-warning/. Look like they found a solution

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you can't use dev/canary builds the easiest way to remove the pop-up is to package your extension and then use group policies to whitelist it, as outlined here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/38011386/991321

Comment: This will not work if you are on a windows home edition as google desided to ignore the group policies altogether... just one more sip of google love...

Answer (score 4):

I am adding here the official ways to solve this issue and I know they are not optimal, but it makes sense that these solutions are present here.

The first solution and the most complicated one is to create a `Google Store Account` and go through all the steps to activate it, with it you can upload your `extension package` and keep it `Private`, so you can share the link to this package to who will need to install it, this way that message will never show since the extension has been approved by Google team and it's secure.

The second option is to download the `Chrome Dev Browser`, linked [Here](https://www.google.com/chrome/browser/desktop/index.html?extra=devchannel), it wont show on the screen that you are downloading the `Dev Channel`, you have to trust it is happening. This version of the browser works side by side with the official version so you don't have to uninstall or anything, and all settings are separated so it's really like a different browser.

I am using version 64 of it and it solved my problem with the extension.

Comment: The problem with Chrome Dev is now it has something weird in it that evidently causes it to crash if you are running programs that affect window placement. I run AquaSnap and it tells me it crashed because of that. But the method with a Google Store Account and having a private extension, that's really good to know, I didn't know that, so thank you.

Comment: Oh that sounds bad @RobKwasowski i always had a good time using Chrome Dev, i guess we are bound to lose that too, when will Google start to work with us instead of against us? :(