# How to get archive of chrome extension?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

Is there an archive of older versions of chrome extensions? The extension I want to recover had 100-200 users. Is there any way I could recover its older version.

Comment: https://www.crx4chrome.com/

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is there an archive for older versions of Chrome Extensions?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10730721/is-there-an-archive-for-older-versions-of-chrome-extensions)